# Draw graphics beneath components

Tags: java, swing, animation, background, jtextfield

So I am currently making a login screen that has a cool looking background effect made using the Graphics object and a 'game loop'. When I add in a `JTextField` though, it is seen underneath everything and not above. Is there anyway to to make the graphics draw underneath all components inside of the `JFrame`?

Here is an image of the graphics:

[image]

The text field is there, just underneath everything being drawn to the surface of the frame. I want to somehow reorder this so it draws underneath components.

Here is my current frame code:

```
    frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextField user = new JTextField(20);
    user.setLocation(100, 200);
    user.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(user);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
    buff = frame.getBufferStrategy();

    Painter painter = new Painter();
    frame.add(painter);
```

Any help please?

Comment: `user.setLocation(100, 200);`  Don't do that, use layouts (+ size hints in constructors, layout padding & borders) for sizing and positioning.

Answer (score 5):

[`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) shows one approach. It overrides `paintComponent()` and invokes `super.paintComponent()` to ensure that components are rendered atop the background. Click anywhere to position a text field; resize to see how the default `FlowLayout` works. `JPanel` is double buffered by default using the existing buffer strategy.

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10836833/418556) for a panel with an animated BG (GIF), as well as the accepted answer on the same question - for the best way to load it.  ;)