# JPanel Not Opening When Instantiated From Other Class

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

In my main class, I call a class that, upon instantiation, should display its JFrame window. However, that is not the case. I've had this class work before, when I ran the project through Eclipse. Now, running it through command line, it does not work :(.

From my main method:

```
PaintTitleMovie q = new PaintTitleMovie();
```

The Jframe class:

```
public class PaintTitleMovie extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    Image image;
    Font ConfettiFinal = new Font("Analog", 1, 20); // fail safe
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public PaintTitleMovie() {
        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("src/Title2.gif");
        try {
            Font Confetti = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(
                    "src/Fonts/Confetti.ttf"));
            ConfettiFinal = Confetti.deriveFont(1, 50);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
        // draw exit button
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(990, 50, 210, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(1000, 60, 190, 80);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(ConfettiFinal);
        g.drawString("Continue", 1000, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                frame.add(new PaintTitleMovie());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(1200, 800);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                SongTitle s = new SongTitle();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x = arg0.getX();
        int y = arg0.getY();

        if (x >= 990 && y >= 50 && y <= 150) {
            this.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
            PaintMenu load = new PaintMenu(); // load paint menu
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatz your error ? In my mind, My wild guess, you will be asked a dependent jar or class files ?

Comment: There is no error unfortunately leaving me as confused as a dragonfly orbiting Pluto. I will be asked for several class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `src/Title2.gif` is going to be problem, the `src` directory will not exist when the program is built.

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(String)` also assumes that the resource is file on the file system, but anything that is contained within the application context (or jar file) is consider an embedded resource and can not be treated as a file.

Instead, you could need to use something more like

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Title2.gif"));
```

This will return a `BufferedImage` but will also throw an `IOException` if the image can not be loaded.  If the gif is an animated gif you will need to use something more like

```
image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Title2.gif"));
```

The same will go for your font, but in that case you will likely need to use

```
Font Confetti = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/Fonts/Confetti.ttf"));
```

If you're using Eclipse, you may need to move these resources out the the `src` directory and in a "resources" directory at the same level as the `src` directory in order for them to be included in the final build.

Comment: It is an animated gif, so I used the ImageIcon method, however, now g.drawImage won't work with an ImageIcon

Comment: It's very hard to paint an animated icon in this manner.  You could use `ImageIcon.paintIcon` method or better yet, add a `JLabel` to the panel and set the `ImageIcon` as label's icon

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648696/why-gif-animation-doesnt-animate-when-using-it-in-paintcomponent)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer! I used your fix and called q.main(new String[1]); and now it runs perfectly :)))))