# Make ImageIcon loop infinitely

Tags: java, infinite-loop, gif, imageicon

I am trying to display an ImageIcon (an animated .gif image file) on my canvas in Java. When I draw the ImageIcon like this:

```
this.character = new ImageIcon("resources/test.gif");

public void render(Point position, GuiComponent gui, Container observer) {
    Graphics graphics = gui.getGraphics();
    character.paintIcon(observer,  graphics, position.x, position.y);
}
```

the gif only loops once, while I would like to get my gif loop indefinitely. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You need to call character.paintIcon(observer,  graphics, position.x, position.y); in a loop on a new thread.

Comment: You could use a JLabel, which will do it automatically, but the question lacks context to know what solution would be best to suggest

Comment: @Aeshang and how do I know at which intervals I have to redraw the icon? or can you only do this by manually installing a specific timeout?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the animated gif is an image of a player in a platform game and is redrawn in each repaint operation.

Comment: You should be able to repeatedly call paintIcon, from my limited experimentation, as long as your refreshing at least at the GIFs frame rate it should paint fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why gif animation doesn't animate when using it in paintComponent()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648696/why-gif-animation-doesnt-animate-when-using-it-in-paintcomponent)

Comment: @Aeshang I indeed have found the answer for showing the gif in that topic, but when I use the .paintIcon the gif only loops once. My question is how to get it looping all the time.

Answer (score 0):

On the newly created icon try using:

```
icon.getImage().flush();
```

and then do

```
label1.setIcon(icon);
```