# Multiple instances of the same animated GIF in a Canvas (Java)

Tags: java, swing, gif, graphics2d, animated-gif

So I'm making a game where you can put bombs on the location of your character. Each bomb is associated with a GIF image when the bomb is displayed and eventually go BOOM (think about Bomberman).

The problem was, when i tried to paint more than one bomb on the screen, it was painted from the last frame of the GIF. Investigating, I found the method image.flush() to reset the GIF cicle but now the problem is that every time I paint a second bomb on the screen, the GIF cycle is reset for all previously bombs on screen.

Here is my constructor for each bomb:

```
public Tnt(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/modelObjects/tnt.gif");
    image = ii.getImage();
    image.flush();
}
```

Every bomb i create enters an ArrayList (listTnt) and is removed after 6 secs, so i only paint the bombs already active.

Here is my method for drawing:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JPanel board){
    for(Tnt tnt: listTnt){          
        g2d.drawImage(tnt.getImage(), tnt.getX(), tnt.getY(), board);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Seems that the problem was ImageIcon, since it reuses the image using Toolkit.getImage. Instead, Toolkit.createImage create a not reusable image.

Here is my new constructor for Tnt that worked perfectly:

```
public Tnt(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
    image = t.createImage("src/main/resources/modelObjects/tnt.gif");
}
```

I dont even need `image.flush()` now. Thank you all.

Comment: What is the scope of `image`?

Comment: Within the main game state of the application i have a list of bombs. When i drop a bomb on the game a new Tnt is created and added to the list and after 6 seconds (bomb lifecycle) the bomb is removed from the list. The `draw` method only paint bombs from the list and `image` is a variable within Tnt.

Comment: See also [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836832/show-an-animated-bg-in-swing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying `Image` is being reused amongst each `ImageIcon`. 
Judging by the [OpenJDK source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/ImageIcon.java#147), it appears to be due to the fact that each simply requests the Image via [Toolkit.getImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage(java.lang.String)).
This method has a nifty caveat, however, which explains the issue at hand:

> The underlying toolkit attempts to resolve multiple requests with the same filename to the same returned Image.

Instead, you should skip the `ImageIcon` step completely (since it's inappropriate to be using a Swing class unnecessarily in the first place), and instead call [Toolkit.createImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String)), which states in the documentation:

> The returned Image is a new object which will not be shared with any other caller of this method or its getImage variant.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation and solution. I added an example code as I tried your solution I was not aware of before.

Answer (score 2):

As I did not know how to solve this, I tried @super_ solution and it works quite nicely. I share the code for anyone who wants an example. +1 to him

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestAnimatedGif {

    private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 9;

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestAnimatedGif.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final Timer t = new Timer(1000, null);
        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count < IMAGE_COUNT) {
                    try {
                        JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                                new URL("http://www.sitevip.net/gifs/bomba/BOMB-B_animado.gif"))));
                        panel.add(image);
                        count++;
                        panel.revalidate();
                        panel.repaint();
                        System.err.println("image added");
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    t.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestAnimatedGif().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```