# Transfer animated GIF over socket

Tags: java, sockets, applet, gif

I worked on a project that i need to transfer GIF to the applet from server over TCP socket.
The problem is that when i transfer the image it become static (the last frame displayed).

I tried to transfer (ICON) where i loaded the image on server side but it has the same result.

So, Is there any class to read animated gif so i can transfer it by ObjectOutputStream?
or any way else?

Server Side:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\Data Files\\simu.gif");
Mat_out.writeObject(icon);
```

Client Side:

```
ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) Mat_in.readObject();
jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use one of the [`createImage(..)` methods of toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#method_summary) methods of toolkit to load the image, but..
2. Add a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) to ensure the *entire image is loaded* before transmitting it.  (This can also work for the image returned from `ImageIcon`, but why create a GUI component that is not needed?)

Alternately load the entire `byte[]` of the image using a blocking method, and provide that to `createImage(byte[])`.

Comment: Does createImage() methods deal with animated images?
as BufferedImage & ImageIO classes doesn't support animated & returns static (last frame) image.

Comment: Thank U very much..
I tried the second option & it works ! :))

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  Re the animation frames, see [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836832/show-an-animated-bg-in-swing) for more details.