# Animated GIF on a JButton, play it when mouse is hovered

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, animated-gif, imageicon

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource( "/img/icon.gif" ) );
aButton = new JButton("Its a button", icon);
```

Is there some kind of method that can stop an animated from playing? 
I was thinking of assigning a static jpg of the gif, then when I hover, assign the animated gif, but I don't think there is an event for taking off mouse in `MouseMotionListener` so I can load back the static jpg.

The gif loops in the button, however, if I hover over it, it disappears.

**How can I make the gif static if my mouse cursor is not on the button?**

If I use `MouseMotionListener`, does it fire an event if I take off my mouse?

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
//play the gif
//if I take mouse off, call some method to stop playing animated gif
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:

- [`setIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- [`setDisabledIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisabledIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- [`setPressedIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- [`setRolloverIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- [`setSelectedIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelectedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)

No need for setting an explicit mouse listener, the changeover happens automatically.

E.G.  In this example I did not add a `MediaTracker` so popped the image into a label to allow for load time.  The end user is the `ImageObserver` (wait till you see it spin before dismissing the first dialog).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageSwapOnButton {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif");

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
        ImageIcon spinIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(spinIcon));

        // create a static version of this icon
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(150,150,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIcon staticIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);

        JButton button = new JButton(staticIcon);
        button.setRolloverIcon(spinIcon);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
    }
}
```

Also, don't make the static image as JPEG.  A JPEG is lossy and does not support transparency.  Either use a single frame GIF or a PNG.

Comment: @Lan Try producing an [animated GIF with `ImageIO`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836832/show-an-animated-bg-in-swing).  ;)

Comment: @Lan That tidbit surprised me when I stumbled across it!  I regularly use `ImageIO` for non animated images, and the occasions I had needed animated GIFs were typically in components that handled it all 'automagically' (buttons, HTML in components etc..).  Despite my trawling through the documentation, I can find no explanation as to why `ImageIO` does *not* produce an animated GIF.

Answer (score -1):

```
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/*icon location*/"));
button.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("/*icon location*/"
```

The Animated gif image will not get invisible when mouse pointer moves over the button.