# Animated gif does not play - mouse listener - event mouse entered

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, mouselistener

I have a button that I have replaced with an image, on hovering I want the image to play an animated gif. I have added a mouse listener and entered the code for changing the image to the gif. The image changes to the gif; however the gif does not animate. I have had a look for previous answers on this site, there are few but none have been able to help.

```
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            try 
            {
                Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images\\button_1_hover.gif"));
                btnShip1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use a `MouseListener` for this, just set up the icon using, 
   [`setPressedIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29),
   [`setRolloverIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) etc.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875475/418556) for an example.
2. Don't attempt to load the image 'as needed', but instead load them & set them up on the button when it is initialized.
3. Change
    `getClass().getResource("images\\button_1_hover.gif")` to
   `getClass().getResource("/images/button_1_hover.gif")`
4. Change the method used to load the image.  ImageIO will not typically load an animated GIF correctly.  See [Show an animated BG in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556) for details.
5. Change code of the form 
   `catch (Exception e) { ..` to 
   `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: +1 been a while since I wrote java completely overlooked `/images/...` and the setXXX methods :|! But will `ImageIO.read` make the gif animated?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  No.  See [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556) for details.