# how to create live tile icons interface using java

Tags: java, live-tile

I need to create Live tile icon interface using java language .. please help.
I tried using JButtons. Setting the size of JButtons as I needed. but I can't figure how to make these icons blink or rotate. If this is possible please help..

Please Mention why my question is voted down???
isn't this possible to create live tile icons using java or is it too much complicated??

Comment: The Java language is not supported by Microsoft for making live tile applications.

Comment: I don't know what a `live tile icon` is, but you can use an animated gif as an icon, at least on a JLabel (don't know if I've tried it on a JButton).

Comment: live tile icons means such that used in windows 8 start menu. so please can you tell  me how to use it on a Jlabal ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Answer in the Stack Overflow It self.. The Solution To make live tile Icons seems to be putting animated GIF on JButton. You can find the answered question at this link.
[Animated GIF on a JButton, play it when mouse is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874831/animated-gif-on-a-jbutton-play-it-when-mouse-is-hovered).