# How to set GIF background for JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, animated-gif

The following code is for making *JDialog*:

```
private class InfiniteDialog extends JDialog {

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/menu_icons/loading.gif")), 0, 0, null);
    }   
}
```

And here is some code for executing:

```
    JDialog dialog=new InfiniteDialog();
    dialog.setSize(300, 300);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

But I can see the dialog without background. Please, tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is located the .gif relative to the root folder of your project ?

Comment: [here are (could be) answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+animated-gif)

Comment: 1) `public void paintComponents(Graphics g)` should be singular, e.g.  `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` 2) Do not try to load an image in the paint method!  Nothing potentially long running whould be done there. 3) A `JDialog` is an `ImageObserver` so `null` should be `this`. 4) [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10836833/418556) shows how to use an animated BG in a frame.  Maybe it will help. 5) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that hot-links to an image like the source in point (4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to clean + refresh your project in your IDE.
Then try to remove the "/" at the beginning of the path.