# How can I remove flickering from an animated gif in Java?

Tags: java, swing, gif

I've been trying to implement a game using a `BufferStrategy` within a `Canvas` in a `JFrame`, and I just can't seem to get my animated `.gif` images (implemented as `new ImageIcon().getImage()`) to play without flickering.

I think the problem lies with the `.gif` refresh rate and the rate at which the canvas is being redrawn, but this is only a guess. I've been trying various things for hours and searching all over the internet for some solution, but one has yet to present itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note, the `.gif` works fine. It doesn't flicker in image viewing programs like XnView, and it also played fine as a `JLabel` within a super simple `JFrame` program.

Comment: Increase your heap space, may help.

Comment: 1) Don't mix AWT with Swing. 2) Use a JLabel. 3) Why do you want to use a `Canvas` if it works properly with a `JLabel`? Why do you want to change something that works?

Comment: +1 to Guillaume, once i did the same thing, and the flickering went away when i adjusted my heap space, but the actual reason was mixing AWT with Swing.

Comment: I tried removing all Swing components making everything Frame and Canvas. I tried increasing my heap space to 1gb and it still flickered.

Comment: The reason why I am not using `JLabel` is because I wanted to try and directly paint the image on the `Canvas` myself.

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. I made a simple program using only a `JFrame` a `JPanel` and a `JLabel`. That worked fine, so I added in a `BufferedImage` background to my `JPanel` and it still worked. The last thing I tried changing was removing my `JLabel` and having `JPanel.paintComponent()` directly draw my animated `.gif` which reproduced the flickering effect. I want to see if I can try and restrict repaints of the `.gif` to happen only when the animation is finished, but I also need to somehow keep what I've drawn on top of my background (recreate what I had with the JLabel).

Comment: See [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836832/show-an-animated-bg-in-swing) for tips.  Abandon AWT.  You won't get good help with it since most people have forgotten the details.