# Display animated .gif from URL in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, gif

Is there any way to display an animated GIF image in a `JLabel` like a JPEG or PNG image?  I would like to load an animated GIF from a URL to display it in a label.

If I try it with the common method of static images I just receive the first frame of the GIF...

```
url = new URL("http://example.gif");
image = ImageIO.read(url);

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 

picture = new JLabel();
picture.setIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead use:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

See also [Show an animated BG in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556) for why that change works.

In a nutshell, loading an animated GIF using `ImageIO` will create a static GIF (consisting of the first frame of the animation).  But if we pass the `URL` to the `ImageIcon`, it will correctly load all frames of the animation and then run them.

---

So change this:

```
url = new URL("http://example.gif");
image = ImageIO.read(url);

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 

picture = new JLabel();
picture.setIcon(icon);
```

To this:

```
url = new URL("http://example.gif");

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url); // load image direct from URL

picture = new JLabel(icon); // pass icon to constructor
```

Or even this:

```
url = new URL("http://example.gif");
picture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)); // don't need a reference to the icon
```