# JOptionPane does not show the icon, why?

Tags: java, image, swing, joptionpane, imageicon

I could not see the icon with those lines of codes, although it should work.
The code is the following:

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    public class IconOfDialog {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            ImageIcon orignalIcon = new ImageIcon("/Images/icons8-ok-100.png");
            Image iconImage = orignalIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon okIcon = new ImageIcon(iconImage);
            
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Successfully connect to the database",
                                "Successful Connection", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, okIcon);
        }
    
    }
```

Result with no exceptions:

[image]

Comment: To put it simply...The image file can not be found, has the wrong path, or file name, or is corrupt. Is the directory your image is in actually named `Images` or is it named `images` (all lower letter case). Try to use the actual full path to the image and see if that works. The `new ImageIcon("somefile")` does NOT throw an Exeception if it can't find the file, it just returns null. [Give this SO Post a thorough read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901893/what-happens-when-a-path-for-imageiconstring-is-invalid-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, please make sure the `name` or `path` to the image is correct.

[Click to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYh8z.png)

Comment: This would have been better as just a comment.

Comment: Could you send me what's on your screen? And I am thinking that could it be that the image is too big?

Comment: @RedRabbit I added a screenshot. I don't think that the image size is the problem, I have tested an image which has a dimension of 21600*10800px and a size of 28.3MB and it works.